# Assigning an IP address to optical card ports

Tags: networking

I have a  emulex optic card with two ports and I installed an ethernet driver and a hbanyware utility in it.

Now how can I assign an IP address to these ports?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: Ramhound:there is no description abt assigning ip address to ports.